# Creating and seeding many to many relation in asp.net core 3

Tags: sql, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to build a project with asp.net core 3.1 and i want to make many-to-many relation between identity user and another table(book),
I have 2 tables: AspNetUsers(ApplicationUser) and book:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser // It's identity user
{
    ...

    public ICollection<UserBooks> UserBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Book:

```
public class Book
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserBooks> UserBooks { get; set; }
}
```

UserBooks for relation:

```
public class UserBooks
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to seed db and create init data(users and books):

**User:**

- Email: user1@test.com > *this user should has 2 books*
- Email: user2@test.com > *this user should has book 1*

**Book:**

- Id : 1, Name: "B1" > *This book should has 2 users*
- Id : 2, Name: "B2" > *this book should has user 1*

There is some topics about seeding but i dont know how seed other table and identity user table with many-to-many relation

**How should i seed Users and Books and UserBooks ??**

Answer (score 0):

First, populate the Books and Users with the data you want. (If you want a lot of them for testing, you can use GO 25000 after the insert and it will run it 25000 times) Then populate UserBooks. You can do this manually if you need specific relations, or randomly in a WHILE loop, getting random ids for both fields in the range of ids of the Books and Users. You can also use GO <> after the script and it will run it that many times.

Comment: I don't want to create a lot of them, i just don't know **how** should i do it?

Comment: If you want to add then manually, do as I said but without the GO 25000. Just go to your DBMS and insert sample date to Books and Users, and when that's done, add sample relations. (Example: Add Books 1,2,3,4; Add Users 1,2; Add relations to UserBooks (Book 1, User 1, Book 1 User 2, Book 4 User 2))

Comment: I want to add records in db with C# code in asp.net core not manually

Answer (score 0):

I make *ApplicationDbInitializer* class and call it from startup.cs

```
ApplicationDbInitializer.Seed(userManager, roleManager, context);
```

ApplicationDbInitializer:

```
public static class ApplicationDbInitializer
{
    public static void Seed(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var roleName = "admin";

        roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
        {
            Name = roleName,
            NormalizedName = roleName.ToUpper()
        }).Wait();

        if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync("b@b.com").Result == null)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "b@b.com",
                Email = "b@b.com"
            };

            if (userManager.CreateAsync(user, "@Aa123456").Result.Succeeded)
                userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName).Wait();
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Books.AddRange(
            new List<Book> {
                new Book{ Name="B1" },
                new Book{ Name="B2" },
            });

        context.SaveChanges();

        var userIdOfB = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "b@b.com").Id;
        var bookId1 = context.Books.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "B1").Id;
        var bookId2 = context.Books.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "B2").Id;

        context.UserBooks.AddRange(new List<UserBooks>
        {
            new UserBooks{ BookId = bookId1 , UserId = userIdOfB },
            new UserBooks{ BookId = bookId2 , UserId = userIdOfB }
        });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It works, all data save in db and UserBooks table created with relations but when i want to get UserBooks it is null:

```
var res = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "b@b.com").UserBooks;
```

**Can anybody help me plzzz Why res is null??**